# Memory leak despite using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

I have a constructor for a class that initializes a unique_ptr inside of that class with a value passed to it. For some reason, valgrind complains about a memory leak:

```
22,080 (24 direct, 22,056 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
   at 0x4C2C7A7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x4A64FB: VectorBasedNodeOrder::VectorBasedNodeOrder(VectorBasedNodeOrder const&) (VectorBasedNodeOrder.cpp:33)
   /* snip more trace */
```

This is the allegedly offending code, stripped of all the irrelevant stuff:

```
class VectorBasedNodeOrder : public NodeOrder
{
public:
    VectorBasedNodeOrder(const VectorBasedNodeOrder& order);
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Node*>> orderedNodes;
}

VectorBasedNodeOrder::VectorBasedNodeOrder(const VectorBasedNodeOrder& order):
NodeOrder(order),
orderedNodes(unique_ptr<std::vector<Node*>>(
    new std::vector<Node*>(*(order.orderedNodes)))) // <-- line 33
{
}
```

Can you please explain why and how the memory leak occurs?

Comment: Is the memory for the `VectorBasedNodeOrder` object itself properly managed? If that object itself is leaked, valgrind would issue a warning not only for that, but also for its members, including the `unique_ptr` one.

Comment: @jogojapan That was also my first thought, but should valgrind not also issue a warning for the `VectorBasedNodeOrder` instance? It does not, this is the only "definitely lost" warning.

Comment: yes, that's right, there should be another warning in that case. (I had assumed you had simply not look at that yet because it would likely come further down in the list of valgrind warnings.) But what Mark B just said in an answer might be an explanation for that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Based on your comment that the raw `Node` pointers are managed elsewhere and not the problem I'm going to take a wild stab that `NodeOrder` or a further parent doesn't have a virtual destructor, and when your `VectorBasedNodeOrder` is destroyed polymorphically by base class pointer, the child destructor is never called, resulting in the `unique_ptr` never being destructed.

Comment: `NodeOrder` indeed did not have a virtual destructor. Will run the test again and let you know.

Comment: This is quite an insightful answer.  I'd almost put money on it.

Comment: Though it looks very good as an hypotheses, you are going to lose betting on wild stab.

Comment: This is a great answer and helped me with the same problem as well. Simple, to the point and important!

Comment: I had a similar problem and didn't realize that virtual destructors were needed even if they're empty, thanks.